# .htaccess 301 redirect and remove page.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

So my problem is that I have this running in a sub-directory and there are a couple problems...

1. When I add the 301 redirect I get a 500 error
2. I cannot get "page" removed from the URL (http://174.136.15.245/~clubz/test/page/about-club-z-tutoring-test)

Here is my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    # RewriteRule (.*) http://174.136.15.245/~clubztutors/test/ [R,L]

    RewriteBase /~clubz/test/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?/$1 [R=301, L]
    # RewriteRule ^page.php?p=$1 page/([^/.]+)/?$ [R=301, L]
    # This works but add "page" directory
    RewriteRule ^page/([^/.]+)/?$ page.php?p=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I did look through some other solutions here but I still could not get this to function exactly the way I needed. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackpot! Well, at least on getting page removed from the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ page.php?p=$1 [L]
```

The redirect still doesn't work but it would be nice to have. For now I'll run with this.